# How to read this XML in the below mentioned format - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Trying to transform the below XML into table structure in SQL Server.

```
<SearchKey EntityType="2" userid="12" QName="search1">
    <Groups>
        <Group seq="1">
            <GroupID>1</GroupID>
            <Column seq="1">2</Column>
            <Column seq="2">3</Column>
        </Group>
        <Group seq="2">
            <GroupID>2</GroupID>
            <Column seq="1">1</Column>
            <Column seq="2">2</Column>
        </Group>
        <Group seq="3">
            <GroupID>3</GroupID>
            <Group seq="1">1</Group>
            <Column seq="2">2</Column>
        </Group>
        <Group seq="4">
            <GroupID>4</GroupID>
            <Group seq="1">1</Group>
            <Group seq="2">2</Group>
            <Column seq="3">3</Column>
        </Group>
    </Groups>
</SearchKey>
```

Tried reading the XML with the below code, but the expected output is not achieved. Please help!

```
SELECT a.b.value('GroupID[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS GroupID
    ,a.b.value('Column[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS ColumnSeq
    ,a.b.value('GroupID[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS GroupID1
FROM @XMLString.nodes('/Groups/Group') a(b)
```

In this below table format:

```
GroupID SeqID   ColumnValue ChildGroupID
1       1       2           NULL
1       2       3           NULL
3       1       NULL        1
3       2       2           NULL
4       1       NULL        1
4       2       NULL        2
4       3       3           NULL
```

Also tried the below code, but not able to retrieve records in the above format:

```
SELECT a.b.value('GroupID[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS GroupID
    ,a.b.value('(@GrpSeq)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  AS GrpSeq
    ,a.b.value('(GroupID)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  AS GroupID
    ,a.b.value('(Column/@ColSeq)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ColSeq
FROM @XMLString.nodes('SearchKey/Groups/Group') a(b)
```

Thanks for the all the help :)

Comment: By "read" do you really mean you want to transform the XML into the table structure you've shown?  Is that a text table or do you want HTML out?  Your question is very unclear at present.

Comment: Oops, sorry for being unclear. Wanted to transform the XML to table structure.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why have you left out `SearchKey` in your nodes clause? It is there in the XML and you need it in `nodes()` like this `FROM @XMLString.nodes('/SearchKey/Groups/Group') a(b)`

Comment: I'm able to read them using this `FROM @XMLString.nodes('/SearchKey/Groups/Group') a(b)` Thanks Mikael! But I have difficult while transforming them when there are subgroups. For instance: `<Group seq="4">
   <GroupID>4</GroupID>
            <Group seq="1">1</Group>
            <Group seq="2">2</Group>
            <Column seq="3">3</Column>
        </Group>`

Comment: As I see your problem is not only extract the groups table from the xml but also join it with itself to get the subgroups relations

Comment: Thanks for the response Jean! Could you please help me in doing that?